# Post-hoc test for Bayesian ANOVA in R

Tags: r, bayesian, anova, post-hoc

I set up an ANOVA to test for a 2-way interaction. However, for my hypothesis I would need to test whether the levels A and B of facor 1 are different for each level of factor 2. In a frequentist analysis, I would opt for a Tukey post-hoc test to check for these differences, but I do not know how to do it for a Bayesian ANOVA. I used the BayesFactor package in R.